# Render graphics in C to VB control

Tags: c, vb.net, dll, graphics

I have written my own software pipeline for 3D graphics in C (just to prove to myself I could do it) and, having seen it work, I want to use it in DLL form as a library for Visual Basic .NET. I have had good success with mixing C and VB in this way in the past (C does the hard work in a DLL, VB looks pretty), but what I want to do now is a little different. My software renderer needs to display the graphics in a VB form, most likely on a panel. Ideally, I would do one of two things. First, I could create an instance of a Bitmap class in Visual Basic, somehow pass a pointer to the pixel array to a rendering function in C, then paint the bitmap to the panel. Or second, I could somehow control the graphics on the panel more directly, but I'm not sure how that would work. Does anybody know how I could accomplish my goal?

Edit:
Up to this point I have been using SDL to display graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have found what I am looking for here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

I will come back with more information as soon as I try my plan out. Basically, I can get the address of the pixel array for a bitmap with the lock bits method. I can pass this to my C rendering function. It should work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I have decided that this is very inconvenient.